# How to pass form values from Fancybox back to the calling page?

Tags: c#, fancybox

I am using Fancybox to display a form with numerous checkboxes (up to 60) that the user can select up to 5 of them.  Once selected I want those values to be passed back to the calling form.  I am using C# ASP.Net to do this.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways...

**1)** "box" plugins simply add content to the DOM and position it to make it look like a new window, so its not like its a different page layered on top. Using this, you can simply submit the form on 'close' of the fancybox OR create a button in the fancybox content that submits it to either 1) another page or 2) the submission page via ajax and closes the fancybox

**2)** Have a 'mirrored' form on your original page and as the form is filled out the values get placed into the 'mirrored' form as hidden inputs. This would be done through javascript.

The more user friendly method is number 1, as it is what the user expects, but it all depends on what exactly you need to be done.